Is there a way to mount only the file from k8s secret to a pod without disturbing the existing files in the location?
I am trying to mount a file secret.txt from the secret to location /opt/tomcat/conf/secret.txt. there are other files at the same location e.g. /opt/tomcat/conf/creds.txt that I want to retain.
This is my deployment.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: tomcat-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: tomcat
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: tomcat
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: tomcat-container
        image: tomcat:latest
        volumeMounts:
        - name: secret-volume
          mountPath: /opt/tomcat/conf/secret.txt
          subPath: secret.txt
      volumes:
      - name: secret-volume
        secret:
          secretName: mysecret
          items:
          - key: secret.txt
            path: secret.txt

The secret mysecret was created using the below command.
kubectl create secret generic mysecret --from-file=secret.txt

But this config creates a directory under /opt/tomcat/conf/ with the name secret.txt/ and further places secret.txt file inside it.
Overall result is /opt/tomcat/conf/secret.txt/secret.txt.
I want it to be like /opt/tomcat/conf/secret.txt
Is there any way to achieve this? Any help would be valuable.
Thanks!

Can you try with subPathExpr instead of subpath like replace the subPath as subPathExpr: secret.txt .

Hello @Mayank Singh Rathore , if you think that my answer was helped you, please consider accepting (✔️) or upvoting it. I'd really appreciate it. Have a great day, Thank you!

By default the subPath property will create a new directory under the path given as mountPath. So, In your case you can try with subPathExpr which helps to mount the volume into the existing directory without affecting the pre-existed content in the directory as shown below:
   spec:
      containers:
      - name: tomcat-container
        image: tomcat:latest
        volumeMounts:
        - name: secret-volume
          mountPath: /opt/tomcat/conf/secret.txt
          subPath: secret.txt
      volumes:
      - name: secret-volume
        secret:
          secretName: mysecret
          items:
          - key: secret.txt
            path: secret.txt

Note: Before using, check if the subPathExpr field supports your kubernetes version or not.
